# Многострочный ввод в файл .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, который должен выполнять такую задачу как записывание из многострочного input() в .txt файл, с чем он успешно не справляется, неизвестно по какой причине, причем при записи никаких ошибок не возникает, а после нажатия ctrl + D возникает ошибка приложенная ниже.

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
    with open("some.txt", "a") as ouf:
        ouf.write(input() + "\n")








\\\\\\
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/python-projects/test/main.py", line 10, in <module>
ouf.write(input() + "\n")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Может, стоит сначала изучить основы программирования и языка, а не тупо копировать куски кода из ответов на Ваши вопросы?

Comment: а что должна сделать комбинация `ctrl + D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо input(), используйте line:

```
with open("some.txt", "a") as ouf:
        ouf.write(line + "\n")
```

и у вас бесконечный цикл, поэтому вам нужно его остановить:

```
if line == 'stop':
   break
```